# In-memory ClassLoader with Eclipselink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have an in-memory classloader which I use to load a JPA-Entity.

```
 private static class InMemoryClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private final Map<String, ByteJavaFileObject> fileObjects = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, Class<?>> cachedClasses = new HashMap<>();


    public InMemoryClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (fileObjects.containsKey(className)) {
            if (!cachedClasses.containsKey(className)) {
                ByteJavaFileObject fileObject = fileObjects.get(className);
                cachedClasses.put(className, defineClass(className, fileObject.getByteCode(), 0, fileObject.getByteCode().length));
            }
            return cachedClasses.get(className);
        } else {
            return super.findClass(className);
        }
    }

   @Override
   public Class<?> loadClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (fileObjects.containsKey(className)) {
           return findClass(className);
        } else {
            return super.loadClass(className);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String className) {
       return new ByteArrayInputStream(fileObjects.get(className).getByteCode());
    }
...
}
```

And I create an EntityManagerFactory using this Classloader.

```
 Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
 properties.put("eclipselink.classloader", inMemoryClassLoader);
 EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pack", properties);
 entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

Now when I try to load a correctly annotated class beforehand and then use it (`entityManager.find(inMemoryClassLoader.findClass("pack.test"), 0)`) I get the following exception.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity bean class: class pack.test, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.`

My **persistence.xml** looks as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="pack">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>pack.test</class>
    <properties>
        ... // properties tested
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I did allot of research but could not find any example of someone trying to do the same thing as I want to do. Basically I want to compile and load class-strings that are generated during runtime without saving the file to disc. Afterwards I want to use these files to get a database entry. (For testing purposes)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fits your use case, but have you checked [dynamic persistence](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic) in EclipseLink?

Comment: I had a look at this already. I would need to add a lot of boilerplate for something that I already wrote (I create JPA entities as strings). I found one mistake which was in the getResourceAsStream() method. There not the className is passed but rather the resourceName. This fixed my problem!

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to enable weaving with these classes and I am golden :D